# Two models in django

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django so I don´t know about this.

What is happening is that I have two tables.

1. Table BlogPost : Save all post.
2. Table Categoria : Save the ID of the category of register post.

**My model.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):

    title=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    categorias_post = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria)
    body = RichTextField(('Content of post'))
    creada_en = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    actualizada_al = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**My forms.py**

```
class FormularioPost(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'categorias_post', 'body')
```

**My views.py**

```
def postregistrado(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormularioPost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save

        messages.success(request, 'Su post ha sido registrado con éxito.')
    else:
        form = FormularioPost()

    return render_to_response(
        "postRegistrado.html",
        locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
        )
```

I want to insert in two different tables from the same `views.py`. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `commit=False`, you have to explicitly call `save_m2m()` to save the many to many fields.

```
if form.is_valid():
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.author = request.user
    post.save() #Note that it is a function call.  
    post.save_m2m()
```

You can read more on this in the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

> Another side effect of using commit=False is seen when your model has
>   a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a
>   many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a
>   form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the
>   many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save
>   many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the
>   database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using
>   commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm
>   subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the
>   form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data.

Another thing is, make sure you add the [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) on this view, so that you don't run into weird issues when `post.author = request.user` evaluates to anonymous users